# Wants to add a New Column into Slowly Changing Dimension, but gets Error

Tags: sql, etl

We have a slowly changing dimension ETL package, which reads data from Task table to update DimTask table. The thing is that, we added a new column 'Category' into Task table, and want DimTask to slowly change on it (that is, once the value of 'Category' of one TaskID is changed in Task table, we want to add a new row in DimTask table to record this new value with new start and end date).

So we inert 'Category' into both Task and DimTask table, then we added the 'Category' in advanced editor of the ETL package, as well as the OLE DB Source and Insert Destination. The Error here is that, the advanced editor says 'There must be at least one column of Fixed, Changing, or Historical type on the input of a Slowly Changing Dimension transform.'

We are not sure why this appears, does this mean we have to use the Slowly changing dimension Wizard to go through the process (like choose primary key, which columns are historical) all over again each time we want to update the slowly changing dimension?

Is there any way we could only add this new column? Because we have hundreds of other columns in the table and it would costs lots of time to go through the Wizard again.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh we found that the column type of 'Input columns' under slowly changing dimension's advanced editor's 'Input and Output Properties' would be automatically deleted when adding a new column. Once we fill the Column types (especially the Key type), the ETL starts to work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQjGf.png)